# Type hinting with many possibilities in python

Tags: python, python-typing

What is the best way of type hinting with many possible inputs?

For instance, for a function:

```
def example(input1):
    return input1
```

If `input1` is one of, for instance, 10 possible classes, is it still best using `Union`, or is there a better method?

Comment: Why so many classes? Do they share an interesting superclass or `typing.Protocol` that you could use for the type hint, or should your function really be two or more separate functions?

Comment: Attempting to apply static typing often reveals poor design decisions that should be addressed.

Comment: i go with @chepner and would recommend a superclass (could be abstract base class) to group them

Answer (score 0):

The type of the identity function is usually:

```
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')


def identity(x:T) -> T:
    return x
```

Comment: The OP presumably wants to restrict which classes can be bound to `T`, though.

Comment: @chepner usually the best choice is to return the same type, instead of trying to implement a type parameterized over its own subtypes, or a union type where you lose virtually all type information. YMMV etc. Python's type system is pretty anemic though, so I'd probably go for an `if not isinstance(x, (list-of-classes):` at the beginning of the function if I really cared...

Comment: You aren't answering the question. As asked, `Union` seems to be the *only* option; neither using an unconstrained type variable nor adding a run-time type check is an alternative type hint to `Union`.

Comment: @chepner I guess I'm answering that there is no good way, but if you want to write a more in-depth answer I'm sure you'll get my upvote ;-)